# Can sub-uranic elements produce a nuclear explosion if they are exposed to an extreme neutron flux?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

I believe that the gun-type nuclear bomb dropped on Japan used a neutron flux generator to help its uranium go critical.

I also believe that while sub-uranic elements can undergo fission, they always produce less energy than they take in, so they cannot form a chain reaction.

The question is, if we assume that there is some enormous neutron flux beam being powered into a mass of sub-uranic material, like, let's say, an adversary's space ship - is it technically possible that the neutrons can force the material to go fissile?

I'm open to being told I'm wrong about how the whole thing works, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by “gun-type” when referring to a nuclear bomb?

Comment: @Ghoster, Re "gun-type," The [_Little Boy_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy) bomb that was dropped on Hiroshima was a "[gun-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun-type_fission_weapon)" weapon. It was very inefficient compared to all of the other nuclear weapons designed since then, but they built it because they were in a big hurry to use it, and the physicists were sure that the gun-type would work even without testing it. They weren't so confident about [the other kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon_design#Implosion-type_weapon).

Comment: @Ghoster - Little Boy is a gun-type device - it literally fires one chunk of U into the other. It was based on a US Navy gun.

Comment: Little Boy had neutron initiators that were sources of neutrons that were then multiplied by the critical mass of U235. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Boy#Design

Comment: This question is pretty vague. You are really asking us to study every isotope of every element and decide if an arbitrary amount of neutrons of an arbitrary energy could result in a large release of energy. You need to make that a little more focused.

Answer (score 0):

Lithium 6 readily fissions into tritium and helium when it captures a neutron. The fission products are easy to detect, so it's used in neutron detectors. It cannot produce a fission chain reaction since it does not yield neutrons.